# How does one redirect using an Apache Perl Handler?

Tags: apache, perl, redirect, cgi, cgi-bin

I have an Apache Handler that sets an extension, `.redir`, to a Perl script.  The code is as follows:

```
Action redir-url /cgi-bin/redir.pl
AddHandler redir-url .redir
```

The script should simply redirect the user to the page contained in the `.redir` file.  Example:

`so.redir`:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/
```

If the user visits `http://example.com/so.redir`, they will be redirected to `http://stackoverflow.com/`.

My current code is as follows, though it returns an error 500, and probably is completely off:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Path::Class;
use autodie;

my $file = file($ENV{'PATH_TRANSLATED'});

my $file_handle = $file->openw();

my @list = ('a', 'list', 'of', 'lines');

foreach my $line ( @list ) {
    # Add the line to the file
    $file_handle->print("Location: ".$line."\n\n");
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: The header is missing the status code. You're also outputting headers in a loop, which makes no sense.

Comment: How many places do you think you can redirect a client to in a single response? :)

Comment: This was just copying and pasting various pieces of code from the internet, so it's a bit impractical :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back in the cgi-days we used to have a small subroutine that does the redirecting:

```
sub redirect_url {
    my ($url, %params) = @_;

    $params{Location} = $url;

    if ( ($ENV{'HTTP_USER_AGENT'}=~m|Mozilla\/4\.|)
        && !($ENV{'HTTP_USER_AGENT'}=~m|MSIE|) ) {

        # handle redirects on netscape 4.x
        $params{Status} = '303 See Other'
            unless exists $params{Status};
        $params{'Content-Type'} = 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
            unless exists $params{'Content-Type'};
        $params{Content} =<<EOF;
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="JavaScript"><!--
location.href = "$params{Location}";
//--></script>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <a href="$params{Location}">Redirect</a>
  </body>
EOF
    }
    else {
            $params{Status} = '301 Moved Permanently'
            unless exists $params{Status};
        $params{'Content-Type'} = 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
            unless exists $params{'Content-Type'};
    }

    $params{Expires} = 'Fri, 19 May 1996 00:00:00 GMT'
        unless exists $params{Expires};
    $params{Pragma} = 'no-cache'
        unless exists $params{Pragma};
    $params{'Cache-Control'} = 'no-cache'
        unless exists $params{'Cache-Control'};

    my $content = exists $params{Content}
        ? $params{Content} : $params{Status};
    delete $params{Content};

    while (my ($key, $value) = each %params) {
        print "$key: $value\n";
    }
    print "\n";
    print $content;

    exit 0;
}
```

so if I get the rest of your code rite:

```
use strict;
my $file = $ENV{'PATH_TRANSLATED'};
open (my $fh, '<', $file) or die 'cant open';
my $url = <$fh>;
chomp($url);
redirect_url($url);
```

would do the job.

Comment: Did you add the she-bang line at the beginning, and the function definition ? Did you set the executable bit?

Comment: Never mind, works perfectly.  I had a bad `use` statement, pointing to a nonexistent class.  Removed it, all is fixed.